# How to get SQL results for specific time (not date)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to search for a specific time across days.

I have a view where I convert DATETIME to time like this `cast(dateRecorded AS TIME) AS TME`

`select * from myView where TME = '08:44:43'` - no results

`select * from myView where TME > '08:44:43'` - I get results with 08:44:43 time

But I need the exact time here, not everything after that date.

Comment: Is it possible that there is some millisecond component in your time value?

Comment: Some sample data and expected results will also help us help you. Reproduce the problem, so we can understand where you've gone wrong.

Comment: Also, there is no SQL Server 2018; it doesn't exist. The latest release is SQL Server 2019, and the version prior to that was 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that DataGrip crops out milliseconds by default, without a warning.

[image: DataGrip vs SqlServer]

Converting to time like this got my desired result  `CONVERT(TIME(0), [dateRecorded]) AS TME`

Answer (score 1):

The problem will be the miliseconds that are present in datatype `DateTime`

```
declare @datetime datetime = '20220311 11:26:01:123'

declare @time_1 time = convert(time, @datetime)
declare @time_2 time = convert(time, convert(datetime2(0), @datetime))
declare @time_3 time(0) = convert(time, @datetime)
```

now if I select all these variables

```
select  @datetime, @time_1, @time_2, @time_3
```

I get this

| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN3 | COLUMN4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/03/2022 11:26:01 | 11:26:01.1233333 | 11:26:01.0000000 | 11:26:01 |

**As you can see, SSMS will not show the miliseconds to you in the first column, but they are still there**

So we need use the time variable that was converted from `datetime2(0)` or from `time(0)`

```
select 1 where @time_1 = '11:26:01'
union all 
select 2 where @time_2 = '11:26:01'
union all 
select 3 where @time_3 = '11:26:01'
```

This will result in

| COLUMN1 |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |

the value in @time_1 is not found, because it still has milliseconds, and thus is not equal to '11:26:01'

If it is possible for you to alter the `datetime` columns into `datetime2(0)` then your problem would be fixed without changing your query, otherwise you will have to use the convert like in my examples.